# How can i place a button always center of the graph

Tags: jquery, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYyPh.jpg)I have one start button.How can i place that start button always center of the graph also when i resize the window it should be always center of the graph.How can i do it?

Js:

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
     var chart = $('#container').highcharts(); 
     var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5);
     var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5); 
     $('. placeBtn').css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
     $('. placeBtn').css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
  });


     var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

     var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.plotWidth  * 0.5);
     var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.plotHeight * 0.5);

     $('. placeBtn').css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
     $('. placeBtn').css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
```

Jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/7skvx8L5/2/

Comment: What is the `span` mentioned in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute`, and add `text-align: center` to the row.

```
.placeBtn {
    /* position: absolute; */
    width:94px;
    background-color:#ccc !important;
    border-color: #000 !important;
    color: #000000;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7skvx8L5/3/)

If you don't like calling text-align for every .col-lg-12, you can add a class to that row like this:

```
<div class='col-lg-12 center'>
```

and in stylesheet:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or do you mean this:

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7skvx8L5/7/)

Comment: it should be center of the graph bottom of the line

Comment: @Niranjk, it is..? Or do you mean it has to stick to bottom of the screen?

Comment: button always should be place center of the graph and above the line at line bottom position.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying... Can you draw a picture or something of desired result??

Comment: pls can u tell me ur mail id

Comment: See updated answer @Niranjk, if that's not what you want, upload picture in your question

Comment: image added..pls check

Comment: @Niranjk, check my updated answer (last link) Hope that is what you mean.

Comment: no..that fiddle is not working perfectly..button position s not correctly updated

Comment: No problem @Niranjk, glad I could help :)

Comment: refilon..I have one doubt. can u explain- left: calc(50% - 48px);

Comment: @Niranjk, `calc(50% - 48px)` what this does is center it. You position the button 50% from the left, and remove the half of the button (48px) in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.placeBtn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 1.2em;
  padding-right: 1.2em;
  background-color: #ccc ! important;
  border-color: #000! important;
  color: #000;
  /* position: absolute; -- removed */
  /* width: 94px; -- removed */
}
```

**Browser resize example (sorry about the image quality) :**

[image]